# How do I use Angular Tree with Angular UI router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, jstree

I am refactoring an older Angular application which uses JStree. Views respond to broadcast events and there is duplicate code to handle those events which can probably be avoided by using Angular services. I think it will be a good idea to move away from boardcasting though and use AngularJS tree component. These views have no routing either.

I am very new to Angular but not new to software development. How can I go about using AngularJS tree component and UI router to route to views based on node click using node values / metadata to pass parameters to my views? Any code samples will be appreciated.